# Keycloak: After logout, the logout session NOT active

Tags: session, oauth-2.0, keycloak, access-token, refresh-token

I have to implement biometric authorization which is based on our current Keycloak(SSO) system.
So I tried to create a long-lived refresh token which is activated even when I logout.

Here is curl:

> curl --location --request POST
> 'http://localhost:8089/auth/realms/EXTERNAL/protocol/openid-connect/token?prompt=consent&scope=offline_access'
>
> --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
> --header 'prompt: consent' 
> --header 'scope: offline_access' 
> --data-urlencode 'client_id=client-credential' 
> --data-urlencode 'refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI4NGRkZDM1OC1kMDFjLTRjODQtYmE2OC00ODA1MzVlNmM5OWIifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2NTY5MDY5NDQsImlhdCI6MTY1Njg5OTc0NCwianRpIjoiMTkzM2IxNzktOWQxMC00ODI5LTlkY2EtZGRiNGM5ZGM1YzY0IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtaWQuc2FmaW4udm4vYXV0aC9yZWFsbXMvRVhURVJOQUwiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi1pZC5zYWZpbi52bi9hdXRoL3JlYWxtcy9FWFRFUk5BTCIsInN1YiI6ImZkMTY3NWVjLWY5YjgtNDRjMS04Yjk5LWJlOTU2M2Y2NTgyMiIsInR5cCI6IlJlZnJlc2giLCJhenAiOiJjbGllbnQtY3JlZGVudGlhbCIsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiI2NDExYzQ2ZC1hMGVmLTRiMDEtOTU0Yi00ZTU4ZTE5Mjc2ZDAiLCJzY29wZSI6ImVtYWlsIHByb2ZpbGUiLCJzaWQiOiI2NDExYzQ2ZC1hMGVmLTRiMDEtOTU0Yi00ZTU4ZTE5Mjc2ZDAifQ.c3ZdvnrG_Y3nuHKIWUGqo-beN-S5MNE-Ywufqym2D54'
>
> --data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' 
> --data-urlencode 'scope=offline_access' 
> --data-urlencode 'client_secret=58f28165-1553-4543-9c66-c2e8c65fexxx'

But I received: *"Session not active"*

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: What exactly is the behaviour you expect? When you *log out* in keycloak, that ends the session. That's what a logout is. Refresh tokens are bound to the session, and when that session ends, the refresh tokens are no longer valid.

Comment: @Quân Đoàn, you need to hide the client_secret in your question, I can get your client's access token from your question information.

Comment: @sonOfRa, exactly as you described, I have to use another way to login our SSO system with biometric authorization